# JMeter: JavaScript is not returning exact data in Response Data Sets

Tags: jmeter

As we all know JMeter is not supporting JavaScript till now, but is there any alternative way to extract data from JavaScript's Response Data (Not generating exact response which we can get using Browser) using Regular Expression Extractor and inject it as parameter for another HTTP Request?

Note: In the response page getting message as "JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript in this web browser is not enabled."

Comment: I've read that 3 times and cannot find a question. Post your code/error message, so that people can actually help you.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message. Actually whatever the response data format i suppose to appear on the response data page is not the same.  So I'm not able to use regular expression extractor to extract the data which i want to inject as a parameters for another HTTP request using jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at *HTML view*. As documentation states:

> The HTML view attempts to render the response as HTML. The rendered HTML is likely to compare poorly to the view one would get in any web browser; however, it does provide a quick approximation that is helpful for initial result evaluation.
>   Images, style-sheets, etc. aren't downloaded.

In your case that view is not very helpful, since page has `<noscript>` tag, which ensures that you only see one message about missing JavaScript. So don't look at it, **use *Text* mode instead**, which gives you the actual page source.

Another confusion you seems have is that JavaScript has some sort of "response data". It does not. JavaScript is a client-side technology, while JMeter is working directly with HTTP requests/responses. So when client issues a new HTTP request (which could be result of JavaScript code, user operation, or anything else), JMeter representation of such request is always the same: HTTP Sampler, which has some response data, which, as I said, bast viewed in *Text* mode.

So bottom line is: likely you have no problem with recording or playback of your script, you are just not checking it correctly.

Comment: For extracting values using Regular Expression Extractor we have to take use of text format only. I was using text mode only and the message which I've posted as a note was also from text mode only.

Comment: That makes no sense. Please post 1. Screenshot showing that error; 2. Full content of the page in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the same request as the browser you should get the same response. If you are receiving only the error message regarding not-enabled JavaScript - your test is not working properly and doesn't mimic all the requests which are being sent by a real browser with 100% accuracy (i.e. you are sending only main request with JMeter while browser does few more [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) which fetch data from the server and actually render the content).

It also means that your test does not make a lot of sense as each JMeter virtual user needs to represent real user using real browser as close as possible with all its stuff ([cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), [think times](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), etc.)

So I would recommend the next steps:

1. Make sure you have **correlation** in place.
2. Make sure you are following recommendations from the [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article.

Once done - compare the request(s) which are being sent by browser and JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) the requests should be exactly the same (apart from dynamic data which needs to be correlated). If there are inconsistencies or missing requests you need to amend JMeter configuration to so JMeter requests would **exactly** match the browser ones.